# Taking derivative of Keras model wrt to inputs is returning all zeros

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

So I have a Keras model. I want to take the gradient of the model wrt to its inputs. Here's what I do

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras import backend as K

num_features = 5

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(60, input_shape=(num_features,), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')
#Run predict to initialize weights
model.predict(np.random.rand(1, num_features))

x = tf.random_uniform(shape=(1, num_features))
model_grad = tf.gradients(model(x), x)[0]
```

However when I print out the value of dmodel_dx I get all 0's.

```
sess = K.get_session()
print( model_grad.eval(session=sess) )
>>>array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]], dtype=float32)
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try `model.layers[-1].output` instead `model(x)`.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the softmax is saturated and therefore giving you very small gradients--try

```
model_grad = K.gradients(K.dot(model.layers[-1].input,model.layers[-1].kernel)+model.layers[-1].bias, model.input)
```