# Keras: calculating derivatives of model output wrt input returns [None]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, derivative

I need help with calculating derivatives for model output wrt inputs in Keras.

I want to add a regularization functional to the loss function. The regularizer contains the derivative of the classifier function. So I tried to take the derivative of model output. The model is a MLP with one hidden layer. The dataset is MNIST. When I compile the model and take the derivative, I get [None] as the result instead of the derivative function.

I have seen a similar post, but didn't get answer there either:
[Taking derivative of Keras model wrt to inputs is returning all zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45337371/taking-derivative-of-keras-model-wrt-to-inputs-is-returning-all-zeros)

Here is my code. Please help me to solve the problem.

```
import keras
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras import backend as K

num_hiddenNodes = 1024
num_classes = 10

(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
X_train = X_train.reshape(-1, 28 * 28)
X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
X_train /= 255
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(num_hiddenNodes, activation='softplus', input_shape=(784,)))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

# Compile the model
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
logits = model.output
# logits = model.layers[-1].output
print(logits)
X = K.identity(X_train)
# X = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(None, 784))
print(X)
print(K.gradients(logits, X))
```

Here is the output for the code. The two parameters are Tensors. The gradients function returns None.

```
Tensor("dense_2/Softmax:0", shape=(?, 10), dtype=float32)
Tensor("Identity:0", shape=(60000, 784), dtype=float32)
[None]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are computing the gradients respect to X_train, which is not an input variable to the computation graph. Instead you need to get the symbolic input tensor to the model, so try something like:

```
grads = K.gradients(model.output, model.input)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. A question first, should K.gradient(model.input, model.output) be K.gradient(model.output, model.input) in your answer? Then, I have tried to use model.input as a parameter. Now it works as it returns [<tf.Tensor 'gradients/dense_1/MatMul_grad/MatMul:0' shape=(?, 784) dtype=float32>].

Comment: I wonder what is the difference between model.input,  K.identity(X_train), and tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(None, 784). They are all tensors with the same shape:  Tensor("dense_1_input:0", shape=(?, 784), dtype=float32), Tensor("Identity:0", shape=(60000, 784), dtype=float32), Tensor("Placeholder:0", shape=(?, 784), dtype=float32). But only the first one can be used to get the gradient.

Comment: @user7367951 Yes the parameter are swapped. K.identity is not connected to the computation graph, you can't use it for anything actually.

Comment: It's `K.gradients` not `K.gradient`

Comment: `tf.gradients is not supported when eager execution is enabled. Use tf.GradientTape instead.`

Comment: @quant It is very rude to just throw error messages at people, ask your own questions if you have issues.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I didn't meant to be rude, I'm just pointing out that this is what happens if you try to run the code in your answer.

Comment: @quant No, there is no information at all, details, versions, etc, so your comment is quite useless.

Comment: tensorflow 2.0.0